# Python, what does [i for i] mean

Tags: python, for-loop

I just started learning python, I solved the problem but there's something that I dont quite understand. What does [i for i mean] in these sentence:

```
def sortByHeight(a):
    iL = [i for i, x in enumerate(a) if x == -1]
    print(iL)
    sL = list(filter(lambda b: b != -1, a))
    sL.sort()
```

Could anyone pls explain to me ?, thank you so much

Comment: It's not `i for i` and the end. Rather: take `i` and `x` from `enumerate(a)` and use only `i`.

Comment: Check out list comprehensions: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe writing it like this

```py
iL = [i for (i, x) in enumerate(a) if x == -1]
```

will help you understand.

The `enumerate` function takes as input an iterable (a list for instance) and returns a `(index, value)` list based on this iterable.
Actually, it returns a generator, not a list but this is the idea.
For example:

```py
list(enumerate([3, 14, 15, 9]))
>>> [(0, 3), (1, 14), (2, 15), (3 9)]
```

Comment: Tks guy. I got i, so noob of me to not understand that way :D